# How to prevent scrolling inside a div until fully visible

Tags: html, css

I have a one-page website with a header of 100vh. Now I want the bottom of the header to stay on top of the page when you scroll down. I had the idea to create a section under the header with a height of 90vh (with the remaining 10 vh for the bottom of the header).

But my problem is that when the cursor is on the section, the browser will scroll inside the section and not fully scroll down the section until it has covered 90vh. So is there a way to scroll down the page first before scrolling inside the section?

Some code to illustrate:

```css
header {
  background-image(...);
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  some text
</header>

<section>
  some info here
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)
You can make the header stay on top of the site simply by giving it `position:fixed`!

Comment: Also, generally it is adviced for you to provide the code you're having trouble with so we get a better idea of what the problem is and how it can be fixed.

Comment: I only want the bottom part of the header to stay on top when scrolling down. It is an image with a height of 100vh.

Comment: Please show us your code to help you better.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't read that right. We will definitely need your code for that, though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure if I understood it correctly, but this might lead you:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 64) {
    $("#menu").css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": "0px"
    });
} else {
    $("#menu").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "64px"
    });
}
});
```

Also this uses jQuery, but I think it's readable and it displays my solution that I just copied from my project

This is a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nooorz24/L9pr8sj9/6/

Comment: Change #menu to header, set top to 0px, and set it as absolute at beginning, add margin-top to your content an set it 100vh

Comment: As I'm now on a phone I can't finish it, but you have to fugure out what to put in 64s place in beginning

Comment: Also set bgcolor to header and set width to fit screen for testing purposes

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed response. Please read what I just said to the other guys maybe that makes more sense to you...